# How to make a Atomic Increment of a numeric field in dynamodb using aws-java-sdk 2.0?

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I am developing a system that updates the progress of tasks,
always incrementing by 1 a progress attribute into the dynamodb task table.
I want to do that using the atomic increment of the attribute.

How can I do that using aws-java-sdk 2.0?
I did several kinds of research related to this subject. But I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax under "UpdateExpression".

SET - Adds one or more attributes and values to an item. If any of these attribute already exist, they are replaced by the new values. You can also use SET to add or subtract from an attribute that is of type Number. For example: `SET myNum = myNum + :val`.

In this case `:val` always equals 1 then.

I can not give guaranties (and have not tested it) but this seems to me like it should be Atomic.

PS. One of my first StackOverflow comments, constructive feedback very welcome.